# Code Signing a ColdFusion-based Web Application

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion, code-signing

Is there a tool and an industry-standard that ensures and verifies the integrity of patches or system updates. As part of the release process, sometimes, I deliver an update set to a ColdFusion/HTML/JS based application. My question is whether I can actually sign the package or individual updates out-of-the-box and then have them verified automatically by ColdFusion/application server before getting them installed.

Please note, that sometimes I need to deliver an update to a single JS file and sometimes to a set of ColdFusion, cfc/cfm, files for instance.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're deploying internally and your company uses SVN for repository management, you can use it to do code signing.  I'm sorry, but I can't give you a link; but a google search shows there's a plugin you can use.  You'll probably have to do a bit of digging to figure it out though.  I've never done it before.

Answer (score 1):

For integrity verification (which isn't as strong as code signing) we use [jacksum](http://www.jonelo.de/java/jacksum/index.html).

Here's how we use it:

- We use Ant to create a release, although because CF doesn't need compiling,  that's largely a case of copying and zipping files up.
- During the build, we call jacksum to run over the code we're about to release and it writes the checksum of each file in the app to a single file. We name that file x.y.z.chk, where x.y.z is our version number.
- The generated file is shipped along with the rest of the code.
- There is a screen in our application which gets the .chk file (according to the version it thinks it is running) and reads it. It then reads/checksums the application and reports on any inconsistencies. Essentially we've re-implemented a simple version of jacksum in CF. We could also have called jacksum to do the checking.

This isn't as strong as having a signed package of code, but what we're trying to protect against is partial deployment and corruptions. We're not doing it for strong security reasons: the checksum file is on the same drive as the code, so if you can alter one, you can alter the other,  although by the time someone is able to edit your application's source, you have bigger problems.

If you want to persue this approach I can dig out the jacksum settings we use and the CF code to run the same checksum on a file.

Comment: Barnyr, thank you for answer! Your solution is elegant. For my purposes, I would just have to encrypt the chk file with a private key.  

It would be great for everyone, if you have time, if you can share or give tips how you interfaced with Jacksum through CF.